# Does using React Hooks drastically reduce how code can be reused in React / Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Let's say we have the old traditional way of React / Redux:  (you don't need to expand the code if you are familiar with it:)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function Count(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.increment}> + </button>
      {props.count}
      <button onClick={props.decrement}> - </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  count: state.count
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }),
  decrement: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' })
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Count);
```

Now, using React Hooks `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()`, the above code could be written as this way:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

function Count() {
  const count = useSelector(state => state.count);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const increment = () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' });
  const decrement = () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' });

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increment}> + </button>
      {count}
      <button onClick={decrement}> - </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Count;
```

Both versions work exactly the same, by themselves, except, isn't version 1 highly reusable for `Count`?  That's because using a different `mapStateToProps()` and `mapDispatchToProps()`, we can use `connect()` again to create another `CountNoodle()` and now we have reused `Count()`.

For version 2, `Count()` is hard-wired with what state and dispatch it uses, so the whole `Count()` is entirely not-reusable.  That is, it *has to* be used with that particular state and particular dispatch, but nothing else.  Isn't it true?  So is version 2 above not recommended and actually you would have a version 3, which is not to call it `Count()` but called it `CountNoodle()` and "wire up" the state and dispatch, and re-use `Count()`, which would be simply "presentational"?

So it may look something like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

// Count() actually would be in a different file and CountNoodle.js
//   would import that file
function Count({count, increment, decrement}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increment}> + </button>
      {count}
      <button onClick={decrement}> - </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function CountNoodle() {
  const count = useSelector(state => state.countNoodle);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const increment = () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT_NOODLE' });
  const decrement = () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT_NOODLE' });

  return <Count ...{count, increment, decrement} />;
  // or   return Count({count, increment, decrement});
}

export default CountNoodle;
```

Comment: Maybe, depends on needs. But if you think about it, isn't that *really* all the `connect` HOC is? A container component to map redux state and actions to props a presentational component consumes?

Comment: I think if depends on needs, then the usual need is that we should be able to reuse code...  because if our need is 2 observers all the time, we don't even need to use the observer pattern -- we can just hard wire everything, and when data change, always call the 2 functions. So if we say, there is only one `Count` in the whole app, we can do whatever we want, hard wire everything, but that usually is not a software "best practice"

Answer (score 1):

I addressed this question in my post [Thoughts on React Hooks, Redux, and Separation of Concerns](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/07/blogged-answers-thoughts-on-hooks/) and my [ReactBoston 2019 talk on "Hooks, HOCs, and Tradeoffs"](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/09/presentation-hooks-hocs-tradeoffs/).

I'd encourage you to read/watch through both of them, but as a summary:

- React hooks in general lead you to a different set of organizational patterns than HOCs do, where components are more responsible for handling their own data fetching requirements internally
- This does result in a different set of tradeoffs than HOCs offer, in terms of reusability and testability

Comment: thank you. besides mentioning the blog and video, can the answer be a self-contained complete answer?

Comment: The question is pretty vague to begin with, so the summary I wrote seems reasonably appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Hoc version (version 1) of your `Count` component is also "hard-wired" with particular state and dispatch. You are doing it when `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Count);`

To compare both hoc and hook approaches to achieve `Count` reuse lets take a look at your original `Count`:

```
function Count(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.increment}> + </button>
      {props.count}
      <button onClick={props.decrement}> - </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And to reuse it with hocs you'll go like:

```
const withCount = (field, Component) => connect(
  state => ({ count: state[field] }), 
  dispatch => ({
    increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT', payload: field }),
    decrement: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT', payload: field })
  })
)(Component)

const NoodleCount = withCount("noodle", Count)
const DrinksCount = withCount("drinks", Count)
```

And for the hooks you could:

```
function useCount(field) {
  const count = useSelector(state => state[field]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const increment = () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT', payload: field });
  const decrement = () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT', payload: field });

  return {count, increment, decrement}
}

const NoodleCount = () => <Count {...useCount("noodle")} />;
const DrinksCount = () => <Count {...useCount("drinks")} />;
```

Obviously, there are pros and cons for both of approaches but:

> Does using React Hooks drastically reduce how code can be reused in
>   React / Redux?

No, hooks can not be the source of troubles in component reusability.

Hope it makes sense

Comment: I am trying to understand... how come you a `useCart()` hook and it is hard wire to `NOODLE_COUNT` but is some kind of "cart" but not a "count"... is it a cart as in shopping cart?  `CountNoodle()` uses `<Count>` with a `value` but `Count` doesn't take a `value`...

Comment: yeah, I thought of "noodle" as some item in shopping cart, but the names here may vary for each domain, it doesn't matter. I just forgot to add the `value` prop, sorry.

Comment: the `count` actually can be a component on the page, just keeping track of how many noodles the customer want to order... and the count of drinks, and count of snacks... so 3 counts in an app, for example

Comment: then it doesn't make any sense to me.. what is `increment` and `decrement` for in this case?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't store components in redux state

Comment: `increment` is, for example, the waitress touch a button to increment the number of noodles the customer wants, and it'd show on the screen...  `Count` is actually a pretty simple counter component...

Comment: I think you re-factored it so that creation of new components is even easier. Is the `with` in `withCount()` syntax actually common in React/Redux usage?  I think my version 3 also addressed the reusability issue... I haven't tested the actual code but basically it is to have HOC: specify what the state and dispatch is, and then pass to a pure, innocent, presentational component

Comment: `with` is common for [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) naming